# Trouble with OAuth 2.0 in my Facebook application

Tags: php, facebook

evertything was running fine in my facebook application until I upgraded it to OAuth 2.0, and im not sure if im doing everything right.

The thing is that I already made the OAuth dialog to work and when the user authorizes the app, it renders my app into the iFrame, but I am having trouble with my $_GETs[], let me explain:

Here's my index.php, which I use as the main page, while i just include() some file in a div called content, depending on the $_GET['section']:

```
    $app_id = "xxx";
$application_secret = 'xxx';
    $canvas_page = "xxx";
    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$app_id. "&redirect_uri=".urlencode($canvas_page)."&scope=publish_stream,offline_access";

 //OAuth 2.0

    function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {

        list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

        // decode the data
        $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
        $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

        if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
            error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
            return null;
        }

        // check sig
        $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
        if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
            error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
            return null;
        }

        return $data;
    }

    function base64_url_decode($input) {
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
    }
//
$data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST["signed_request"],$application_secret);

    if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
          echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
    } else {

    $_SESSION['on'] = 1;
    include ('src/facebook.php');

    $files = array();
    $files['RE'] = 'xxx.php';
    $files['RC'] = 'yyy.php';
    $files['DP'] = 'zzz.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $app_id,
        'secret' => $application_secret,
        'cookie' => true, 
        'perms' => 'publish_stream, offline_access',
        ));
    $_SESSION["access_token"] = $data["oauth_token"];
    $me = $facebook->api('/me?oauth_token='.$_SESSION["access_token"]);

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
    <meta property="og:title" content="title" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="description" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <?php include("inc/app_header.php");?>
            <div class="content">
            <?php 
                if(isset($_GET['section'])) 
                {
                    $file_to_include = 'inc/'.$files[$_GET['section']];
                }
                else 
                {
                    $file_to_include = 'inc/section_restaurantes.php';
                }

                include($file_to_include);
            ?>  
                <div class="content_bottom_space"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php } ?>
```

and the code for section_restaurantes is:

```
    <div class="section_restaurantes">
        <div class="restaurantes_container">
            <div class="restaurantes"><a href="index.php?section=DP"></a></div>
            <div class="restaurantes"><a href="index.php?section=PH"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The thing is that when I click in those divs all my browser is reloaded, the ?code= parameter in the url changes twice and it reloads again on section_restaurantes.php, instead of loading the DP section, I hope I'm clear.

I think because its reloading twice i loose the $_GET['section'] parameter and then it loads the default which is "inc/section_restaurantes.php"

I need help please, I've tried to find solutions on the internet but I found nothing.

Comment: You are aware with the PHP-SDK you don't really need to parse the signed_request your self or even set the session, right?

Comment: I'm not sure how to retrieve the access token with another method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse the `signed_request` if you are using the PHP-SDK as it'll take care of that for you. You just need to retrieve the user (`getUser()`) and if no user, redirect to the login url (refer to the [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) file).

Here is a better code:

```
<?php
include ('src/facebook.php');
$app_id = "xxx";
$application_secret = 'xxx';
$canvas_page = "xxx";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $app_id,
    'secret' => $application_secret
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if(!$user) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'redirect_uri' => $canvas_page,
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,offline_access'
    ));
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
    exit;
}

$_SESSION['on'] = 1;
$files = array();
$files['RE'] = 'xxx.php';
$files['RC'] = 'yyy.php';
$files['DP'] = 'zzz.php';
try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <?php include("inc/app_header.php");?>
        <div class="content">
        <?php 
            if(isset($_GET['section'])) 
            {
                $file_to_include = 'inc/'.$files[$_GET['section']];
            }
            else 
            {
                $file_to_include = 'inc/section_restaurantes.php';
            }

            include($file_to_include);
        ?>  
            <div class="content_bottom_space"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now for your restaurant section, I would link to the parent document:

```
<div class="section_restaurantes">
    <div class="restaurantes_container">
        <div class="restaurantes"><a href="<?php echo $canvas_page; ?>?section=DP" target="_top"></a></div>
        <div class="restaurantes"><a href="<?php echo $canvas_page; ?>?section=PH" target="_top"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Assuming your `$canvas_page` is the intended destination.